# How to remove checkall option in extjs checkboxmodel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

How to remove check all option is extjs 4 checkboxmodel?

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have managed to hide it using pure CSS:

> [image]

Code:

```css
.x-column-header-checkbox {display:none;}
```

Comment: That's what I remember doing in Ext JS 3.

Answer (score 6):

When defining a grid (in 4.2.1), set this config option to:

```
selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', { showHeaderCheckbox: false }),
```

(The relevant part is `showHeaderCheckbox :false`)

Comment: Yet another undocumented feature in extJS. Thanks for this!

Comment: To be fair, I just looked up the most recent version of the docs and it's in there but not for the version we were using.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on where to use this? with a small sample checkboxmodel

Comment: @Freakyuser When defining a grid in 4.2.1, set this config option to: `selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', { showHeaderCheckbox: false })`

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating your `checkboxmodel`, try specifying `injectCheckbox: false` into its configuration. [From the API](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel-cfg-injectCheckbox):

> Instructs the SelectionModel whether or not to inject the checkbox header automatically or not. (Note: By not placing the checkbox in manually, the grid view will need to be rendered 2x on initial render.) Supported values are a Number index, false and the strings 'first' and 'last'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried that and it hides all the checkboxes

Comment: Fair enough. I'll do some more poking around in the API, see what I can find.

Answer (score 1):

Inside grid panel afterrender event using jquery

```
listeners: {

        afterrender: function (grid) {
           $('.x-column-header-checkbox').css('display','none');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to API, the type of "header" property is String. Said that, the correct value is ''. It has worked for me on ExtJS 3.4

```
this.queueSelModel = new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel({
            singleSelect : true, // or false, how you like
            header : ''
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

heder:false in config or injectCheckBoxHeader = false hide the entire column. CSS solution is class based so any other widget using the same selection model would also hide the entire check.

Comment: that can prevent by adding a cls to the grid and use css like .grid01 .x-column-header-checkbox {display:none;}  so it will be apply to only grid that has grid01 css class

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJS 4 a header config can be provided as below to display a blank or custom text in the header.

```
getHeaderConfig: function() {
                var me = this;
                showCheck = false;
                return {
                    isCheckerHd: showCheck,
                    text : '&#160;',
                    width: me.headerWidth,
                    sortable: false,
                    draggable: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    hideable: false,
                    menuDisabled: true,
                    dataIndex: '',
                    cls: showCheck ? Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'column-header-checkbox ' : '',
                    renderer: Ext.Function.bind(me.renderer, me),

                    //me.renderEmpty : renders a blank header over a check box column
                    editRenderer: me.editRenderer || me.renderEmpty,
                    locked: me.hasLockedHeader()
                };

            },
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue in ExtJS 4.0.7 version.
First I removed checkbox layout:

```
.rn-grid-without-selectall .x-column-header-checkbox .x-column-header-text
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Then I used the following code in afterrender listener of the grid:

```
afterrender: function (grid) {
    this.columns[0].isCheckerHd = false;
}
```

It is not a good solution but it can be used as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the good hints here.
For Sencha 3.4, this is the extremely simple pure CSS I ended up using,

My_Panel_With_a_Grid_Without_Header_CheckBox = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {....
   cls: 'innerpanel hiddeGridCheckBoxOnSingleSelect',
....}

in my CCS file:

.hiddeGridCheckBoxOnSingleSelect  .x-grid3-hd-checker {
    visibility:hidden
}

Answer (score -2):

Define {Header: false} in checkboxselectionModel

```
this.queueSelModel = new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel({
            singleSelect : false,
            header : false
        });
```