# Remove the select all checkbox in extjs checkboxmodel

Tags: javascript, jsp, extjs

I have a checkbox model in my `extjs` page.

```
var saCheckBox= Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {mode: 'SINGLE'});
```

I am using this in a `grid.Panel` through selModel.
I want to remove the check all checkbox from the model.
I found [this](http://aamirposwal.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-remove-check-allheader-checkbox.html) and added a listener accordingly but still I get the check all box.

```
var saCheckBox= Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {mode: 'SINGLE'}, {listeners: {

    afterrender: function (grid) {
       $('.x-column-header-checkbox').css('display','none');
    }
}});
```

I used `display: none` for that particular span which works good in Mozilla but not in other browsers. Can anyone provide a browser compatible solution?

Comment: Found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321645/how-to-remove-checkall-option-in-extjs-checkboxmodel) using CSS.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use: showHeaderCheckbox :false

See example below:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
data: {
    'items': [{
        'name': 'Lisa',
            "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-111-1224"
    }, {
        'name': 'Bart',
            "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1234"
    }, {
        'name': 'Homer',
            "email": "home@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1244"
    }, {
        'name': 'Marge',
            "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1254"
    }]
},
proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'items'
    }
}
});


var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
title: 'Simpsons',
id: 'sheetproductionrestin',
store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
    checkOnly: true,
    showHeaderCheckbox: false,  //here is where it is added.
    mode: 'MULTI'
}),
listeners: {
    cellclick: function (sender, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
        clickedColIndex = cellIndex;
    },
        beforedeselect: function (rowmodel, record, index, eOpts) {
        return (clickedColIndex == 0);
    }
},
columns: [{
    header: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'textfield'
    }
}, {
    header: 'Email',
    dataIndex: 'email',
    flex: 1
}, {
    header: 'Phone',
    dataIndex: 'phone'
}],
height: 200,
width: 400,
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
plugins: [Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
    clicksToEdit: 1,
    pluginId: 'cellplugin'
})]
// ...
});
```

Comment: `var saCheckBox= Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {mode: 'SINGLE'}, {showHeaderCheckbox : false});` is this what you meant? Still it doesn't work.

Comment: +1,  That's great, thank you very much. Although, I did it using CSS as mentioned in my comment.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the `ExtJS 6.7.0` Modern Toolkit but I think this works with the classic version.

In the following code, I'm setting `headerCheckbox` to `false` in the `selectable` object literal.

```
Ext.define('TestCheckboc.MyGrid') {
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Grid',
  selectable: {
    columns: false,
    cells: false,
    checkbox: true,
    checkboxColumnIndex: 0,
    checkboxSelect: true,
    headerCheckbox: false,
    mode: 'single'
  },
  items[{
    // ...
  }]
});
```

Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image: Grid image]